# Simple function to read file from an URL to a string buffer ( C++ / MQL{4|5} using WinInet.dll )

Tags: wininet, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I am looking for a simple function which is able to read a text or binary file from the internet into a **`string`** variable.

It´s unbelievable that I could not find anything in the web, just low level descriptions of all the `WinInet` functions and useless samples, that do not work at all, at the `MQL`-forums.

What I need is a function like:

```
string buffer = ReadTextFileFromWeb( "www.myurl.net/textfile.txt" );
```

No more, no less. I am not very familiar with internet programming stuff at all, but I am sure there is anybody out there who is able to present the reason just like that.

The code will be used in **`MQL4`**/**`MQL5`**. I know that there is already a `WebRequest()` function which works, but it is restricted to expert advisors and **cannot be used in <kbd>`Custom Indicator`</kbd> type of code.**

I need this solution to load data into a custom indicator.

Comment: Let me ask about the real use-case **cardinal design features** / perfomance envelope: **a) expected length of a `string`** expected to load? **b) is the `string` rather constant or variable** throughout the `Custom Indicator` life-cycle, i.e. does it change at all, or in a per-tick manner or in a "just from time to time" manner?

Comment: Btw. there are even more restrictions for **`WebRequest()`** besides it's ban from being run in `Custom Indicator`. Anyway, there are several ways, how to attack the target, so do not worry, it is doable. Kindly update a few details about performance envelope & will be glad to recommend a feasible solution for given metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Go get this on github https://github.com/sergeylukin/mql4-http

```
//For MT4 Add HTTP Access
#include <mql4-http.mqh>

string URLr = "www.myurl.net/textfile.txt";
Print("URLr return is: ", URLr);
```

For MT5 you are on your own.

The above dose not have the issues that WebRequest() has.  Or I have not seen it have any issues.  I use it all the time in a lot of EA and never had a chart lockup or have a issue.

Comment: "'Shell32' is not a class, struct or union" Got an error like this.

Comment: I am using MT5. Do you haveHTTP access for MT5 ?